# Is there a way to use AWS CodePipeline to conditionally deploy from GitHub based on the existence of a Git tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

In particular, I would like to be able to tag a release in GitHub with a certain pattern (e.g. `"^v[0-9].*"`) and have that trigger an AWS CodePipeline.

Thanks in advance.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

You could create a webhook in Github with apigateway and lambda, and conditionally trigger the pipeline from lambda.

You need to create a lambda function first and then create an api gateway endpoint (POST) pointing to that lambda. Then go to Github > <Your_Project> > Settings > Webhook and create a webhook with the api gateway url. Then you would get the post payload of all events in the event parameter of lambda function you could parse that to get the version or tag details and start the pipeline from lambda using boto3 (python) for example.

Sample payload from github:

```
{'action': 'created', 'release': {'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/releases/33092173', 'assets_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/releases/33092173/assets', 'upload_url': 'https://uploads.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/releases/33092173/assets{?name,label}', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/NiminU/webhooktest/releases/tag/v1.0', 'id': 33092173, 'node_id': 'MDc6UmVsZWFzZTMzMDkyMTcz', 'tag_name': 'v1.0', 'target_commitish': 'main', 'name': 'v1.0', 'draft': False, 'author': {'login': 'NiminU', 'id': 47168398, 'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjQ3MTY4Mzk4', 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/47168398?v=4', 'gravatar_id': '', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/NiminU', 'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/followers', 'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/following{/other_user}', 'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/gists{/gist_id}', 'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/starred{/owner}{/repo}', 'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/subscriptions', 'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/orgs', 'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/repos', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/events{/privacy}', 'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/received_events', 'type': 'User', 'site_admin': False}, 'prerelease': False, 'created_at': '2020-10-27T05:58:22Z', 'published_at': '2020-10-27T06:14:34Z', 'assets': [], 'tarball_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/tarball/v1.0', 'zipball_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/zipball/v1.0', 'body': 'This is the first release'}, 'repository': {'id': 307599246, 'node_id': 'MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzMDc1OTkyNDY=', 'name': 'webhooktest', 'full_name': 'NiminU/webhooktest', 'private': True, 'owner': {'login': 'NiminU', 'id': 47168398, 'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjQ3MTY4Mzk4', 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/47168398?v=4', 'gravatar_id': '', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/NiminU', 'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/followers', 'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/following{/other_user}', 'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/gists{/gist_id}', 'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/starred{/owner}{/repo}', 'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/subscriptions', 'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/orgs', 'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/repos', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/events{/privacy}', 'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/received_events', 'type': 'User', 'site_admin': False}, 'html_url': 'https://github.com/NiminU/webhooktest', 'description': None, 'fork': False, 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest', 'forks_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/forks', 'keys_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/keys{/key_id}', 'collaborators_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/collaborators{/collaborator}', 'teams_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/teams', 'hooks_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/hooks', 'issue_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/issues/events{/number}', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/events', 'assignees_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/assignees{/user}', 'branches_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/branches{/branch}', 'tags_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/tags', 'blobs_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/git/blobs{/sha}', 'git_tags_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/git/tags{/sha}', 'git_refs_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/git/refs{/sha}', 'trees_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/git/trees{/sha}', 'statuses_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/statuses/{sha}', 'languages_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/languages', 'stargazers_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/stargazers', 'contributors_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/contributors', 'subscribers_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/subscribers', 'subscription_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/subscription', 'commits_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/commits{/sha}', 'git_commits_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/git/commits{/sha}', 'comments_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/comments{/number}', 'issue_comment_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/issues/comments{/number}', 'contents_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/contents/{+path}', 'compare_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/compare/{base}...{head}', 'merges_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/merges', 'archive_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/{archive_format}{/ref}', 'downloads_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/downloads', 'issues_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/issues{/number}', 'pulls_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/pulls{/number}', 'milestones_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/milestones{/number}', 'notifications_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/notifications{?since,all,participating}', 'labels_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/labels{/name}', 'releases_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/releases{/id}', 'deployments_url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/NiminU/webhooktest/deployments', 'created_at': '2020-10-27T05:57:32Z', 'updated_at': '2020-10-27T05:58:25Z', 'pushed_at': '2020-10-27T06:14:34Z', 'git_url': 'git://github.com/NiminU/webhooktest.git', 'ssh_url': 'git@github.com:NiminU/webhooktest.git', 'clone_url': 'https://github.com/NiminU/webhooktest.git', 'svn_url': 'https://github.com/NiminU/webhooktest', 'homepage': None, 'size': 0, 'stargazers_count': 0, 'watchers_count': 0, 'language': None, 'has_issues': True, 'has_projects': True, 'has_downloads': True, 'has_wiki': True, 'has_pages': False, 'forks_count': 0, 'mirror_url': None, 'archived': False, 'disabled': False, 'open_issues_count': 0, 'license': None, 'forks': 0, 'open_issues': 0, 'watchers': 0, 'default_branch': 'main'}, 'sender': {'login': 'NiminU', 'id': 47168398, 'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjQ3MTY4Mzk4', 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/47168398?v=4', 'gravatar_id': '', 'url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU', 'html_url': 'https://github.com/NiminU', 'followers_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/followers', 'following_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/following{/other_user}', 'gists_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/gists{/gist_id}', 'starred_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/starred{/owner}{/repo}', 'subscriptions_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/subscriptions', 'organizations_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/orgs', 'repos_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/repos', 'events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/events{/privacy}', 'received_events_url': 'https://api.github.com/users/NiminU/received_events', 'type': 'User', 'site_admin': False}}`
```

You could use the tag_name key from the payload here for your logic

Codepipeline boto3 documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codepipeline.html

Comment: Thanks, Nimin. Could you provide some more details on how, exactly, one would do what you are suggesting?

Comment: You need to create a lambda function first and then create an api gateway endpoint (POST) pointing to that lambda. Then go to Github > Settings > Webhook and create a webhook with the api gateway url. Then you would get the post payload of all events in the event parameter of lambda function you could parse that to get the version or tag details and start the pipeline from lambda using boto3 (python) for example.

Comment: added more details in my answer

Comment: Thanks, Nimin!  I was hoping for something that was more built-in to CodePipeline and could be done via configuration, rather than requiring code on both the GitHub and AWS side.  That said, what you provided is useful, and may be currently the only way to do it, so I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think there is a direct way for this in code pipeline as of now.

Comment: Any blog, or github repo with this solution to be shared maybe ?